# Software Installer does not work

Tags: software-center, 17.04

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04. When I've downloaded an app and try to install it via software installer nothing happens when I press the install button. I have tried this with three different apps and get the same results.

Comment: Give us more information, what is the format of your downloaded files, do you get any error? did you have tested any command to install them?

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same issue here. The downloaded packages are *.deb files, but clicking the downloaded file in Chrome opens the Software app, and I get the Install screen, but clicking the install button does nothing whatsoever.

I've had to resort to installing those packages from the terminal using `sudo apt install` followed by the full path to the deb file. This does work, but it's a little annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing here, when I run

```
sudo dpkg -i *package-name*
```

I'm getting install errors typically and it prompts me to enter

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

After that I can rerun the `dpkg -i` and packages are installing fine, I agree this is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. Is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1672424

While we wait for a solution you can install any -deb package using dpkg on the command line.

```
sudo dpkg -i *package-name*
```

Also, you can install Gdebi from Gnome Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

Un-install the "gnome-software" (Purge the package)

install software center again

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

if the install fail (fix broken install)

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

then retry install using

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```